# IndexOf is missing a value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, indexof

I realize that IndexOf will return a -1 when it doesn't find a value within an array, however, the value that I have it searching for is in the array. I have confirmed this by returning the value in the array with console.log

Here is some of my code (paraphrased for simplicity):

```
var xtiles = [];

function assignValue(tile) {
    xtiles.push(tile); //tile is 1 at this point
    checkArray();
}

function checkArray() {
    var temp = xtiles.indexOf(1);
    console.log(temp); //this returns a -1
    console.log(xtiles[0]); //this returns a 1
}
```

The variable 'temp' should return a 0 since there is a 1 in index 0 of the array xtiles. What am I missing here?

Comment: `[1].indexOf('1') // -1`

Comment: This is exactly what doesn't make sense. If I explicitly set it in the assignVaue function (xtiles[0] == 1) then the indexOf returns a 0.

Is there some sort of conflict with the .push?

Comment: Returns `0` , `1` here . Is input string "1" ?

Comment: title must not equal 1, look here https://jsfiddle.net/9q3ahk13/

Comment: is it possible that title is a string? that would result in a -1 if xtiles[0] = "1" and you're doing a search for the number 1

Comment: You guys are right, I'm reading tile from a value in another function and thought it was returning an integer. I should have checked that first...thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the number `1` is not strictly equal to the string `'1'`.

> `indexOf()` compares searchElement to elements of the Array using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) (the same method used by the `===`, or triple-equals, operator).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the array are strings then you can perhaps search as follows:

```
var temp = xtiles.indexOf(1+""); // force 1 into a string
```